# Why Application_Start called two times from different threads?

Tags: asp.net, events

I can't understand why Application_Start event is called two or three times when my ASP.NET app start? Application_End is not called between Application_Start calls. Also I have only one IIS pool instance.

Comment: Check out:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685158/multiple-application-start-events-firing
Does this apply to you?

Answer (score 6):

Check out:
[Multiple Application_Start events firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685158/multiple-application-start-events-firing)
Does this apply to you?

Also ensure you aren't writing any log entries to the bin folder as that will cause it as well.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the Worker Process Instances. You can find it in the Properties of your Application Pool. This happens if you have more then one instance of worker processes running under the same application pool.