# MVC 5 Application_Start() called multiple times

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, application-start

I am new to MVC 5 and beginner for Visual Studio. I am facing this weird problem.
Every time i change some thing in Layout.cshtml or anywhere in controller or view and run it .The Application_Start() method is called multiple times and i lose all my session data. 
Previously i used to rebuild the solution after changing anything and it was working fine but now that is also now working.
Can anyone please explain me why is this happening.

Comment: Could this be your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685158/multiple-application-start-events-firing

Comment: If you change a controller, that requires a rebuild of the DLL. Any time a DLL changes in your bin folder, that will cause the application to restart.

Comment: Thanks guys JanR. That looks like what happened to me. I moved the solution folder on my workstation and rebuild the project. It working good now. Cheers